# UICollectionView sticky column glitch with contentOffset

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

#### Issue

I've created a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` that uses a sticky top row and sticky left column. With this layout i've also added a pinch gesture to the collectionView to enable zooming.

The zooming works perfect when the collectionView isn't scrolled all the way to the right, or the bottom; when this is true the `contentOffset.x` and `contentOffset.y` are behaving weirdly.

Can anyone spot the problem? I've been trying to debug this issue for some time now.
Here's a gif representation:

[image]

#### Code

**Grid**

```objectivec
- (void)actionPinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
   
   MyCustomLayout *layout = (MyCustomLayout *)self.gridView.collectionViewLayout;
   
   if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
      [layout setPreviousPinchValue:gesture.scale];
   }
 
   if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
      [layout setPinchValue:gesture.scale];
      [layout updatePinchValues];
   }
   
}
```

**MyCustomLayout.h**

```objectivec
@property (nonatomic, assign) previousPinchValue;
@property (nonatomic, assign) pinchValue;
- (void)updateGridScale;
```

**MyCustomLayout.m**

```objectivec
@interface MyCustomLayout() {

    CGFloat zoomLevel;              //  stored zoom level.
    CGFloat cachedSectionWidth;     //  stored original section width.
    CGFloat cachedColumnWidth;      //  stored original column width.
    CGFloat cachedRowHeight;        //  stored row height.

    // these values above are cached when the grid is setup for the first time

}
@end

@implementation MyCustomLayout

- (void)updateGridScale {
   
    float scaleDeltaFactor     =   self.pinchValue / self.previousPinchValue;
    float currentZoom          =   self->zoomLevel;
    float newZoom              =   currentZoom * scaleDeltaFactor;
    float kMaxZoom             =   2.0;
    float kMinZoom             =   0.47;

    newZoom                    =   MAX(kMinZoom, MIN(newZoom, kMaxZoom));

    self->zoomLevel            =   newZoom;
    self.previousPinchValue    =   self.pinchValue;

    CGFloat sectionWidth       =   self->cachedSectionWidth;
    CGFloat columnWidth        =   self->cachedColumnWidth;
    CGFloat rowHeight          =   self->cachedRowHeight;

    sectionWidth = sectionWidth * newZoom;
    columnWidth = columnWidth * newZoom;
    rowHeight = rowHeight * newZoom;
    
    if (newZoom == 1 || newZoom == 0) {
        sectionWidth = self->cachedSectionWidth;
        columnWidth = self->cachedColumnWidth;
    }
    
    self.topColumnWidth = columnWidth;
    self.sectionHeight = rowHeight;
    [self invalidateLayoutCache];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];

}

- (void)prepareLayout {
    
    [super prepareLayout];
    [self prepareAttributesForRows:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.collectionView.numberOfSections)]];
    [self.allAttributes addObjectsFromArray:self.sectionAttributes];
    
}

- (void)prepareAttributesForRows:(NSIndexSet *)sectionIndexes {
    
    NSIndexPath *sectionIndexPath           =   [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:section];
    CGFloat sectionMinY                     =   self.hourHeaderHeight + self.contentMargin.top;
    CGFloat sectionMinX                     =   (self.collectionView.contentOffset.x - 0.5) - self.collectionView.contentInset.left;
    CGFloat sectionY                        =   sectionMinY + ((self.sectionHeight + self.sectionGap) * section);
    CGFloat height                          =   self.sectionHeight + 1;
    
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *atts  =   [self layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewAtIndexPath:sectionIndexPath ofKind:INSEPGLayoutElementKindSectionHeader withItemCache:self.sectionHeaderAttributes];
    atts.frame                              =   CGRectMake(sectionMinX, sectionY, self.sectionHeaderWidth + 1.5, height);
    atts.zIndex                             =   [self zIndexForElementKind:INSEPGLayoutElementKindSectionHeader floating:YES];
    
    NSString *indexPathString               =   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", sectionIndexPath.section];
    NSNumber *y_value                       =   [NSNumber numberWithFloat:round(sectionY)];

    if (![[self.cachedSectionInfo allKeys] containsObject:indexPathString]) {
        [self.cachedSectionInfo setObject:y_value forKey:indexPathString];
    }
    
}

@end
```

Comment: Looks nice, not sure what the problem is though. *Thinking* it may be because, when all the way, you need to ensure the zoom is not such that you add to the ends. E.g. if the size is 100, 100 and you scroll and zoom, the end can become say 120, 120 but this is outside, so somewhere you need to either adjust the zoom or the offsets to stop at such a point that you do not go outside. Thus calculate, given your offset and zoom, the max point of the view on screen, and if that is too big, change either zoom or offset until max point is inside.

Comment: Ahh that's a pretty good solution, it did cross my mind to check against max offset values and adjust, but I thought I could have tripped up in the code somewhere also

Comment: Nice - I hope it solves it, let me know if it does.